# Simba][SpannerJDBCDriver](100300) Error message from server: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Positional parameters are not supported

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

I am using latest JDBC Driver from Google/Simba. I am getting this error when we have a secondary force index as well as with Query Parameter

Simba]SpannerJDBCDriver Error message from server: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Positional parameters are not supported

```
SELECT s.SingerId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Singers@{FORCE_INDEX=SingersByFirstLastName} AS s
WHERE s.FirstName = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Spanner's dialect of SQL does not support positional parameters. [Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/lexical#query-parameters) in Cloud Spanner's dialect of SQL are specified using a `@` followed by an identifier, for e.g.

```
SELECT s.SingerId, s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Singers@{FORCE_INDEX=SingersByFirstLastName} AS s
WHERE s.FirstName = @first_name
```